# CircuiTikZ — create new component

Tags: circuitikz

How can I create a new component and include it in CircuiTikZ? For example a 4 bit adder?

Answer (score 18):

There is an easy way.  Use an existing component as a base, such as
`to[generic,color=white,n=myname]` and draw anything you want in the space.

```
\newcommand{\speaker}[2] % #1 = name from to[generic,n=#1], #2 = rotation angle
{\draw[thick,rotate=#2] (#1) +(.2,.25) -- +(.7,.75) -- +(.7,-.75) -- +(.2,-.25);}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,2) to[C, l_=$C$, o-*] (2,2) to[short, -*] (3.5,2) to[short] (5,2);
\draw (0,0) to[short, o-*] (2,0) to[short, -*] (3.5,0) to[short] (5,0);
\draw (2,2) to[L=$L$] (2,0);
\draw (3.5,2) to[R=$R$] (3.5,0);
\draw (5,2) to[generic, n=S1](5,0);
\speaker{S1}{0}
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

I have improved on my technique since then, as explained in the following tutorials.

http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/speaker.pdf

http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/multipole.pdf

http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/bipole.pdf

Comment: I just want to note that \speaker{S1}(0} should be \speaker{S1}{0}, but it won't let me do a single character edit.  Great example!

Answer (score 16):

Components in *CircuiTikz* are defined in the `pgfcirc*poles.sty` files via pretty much low-level pgf commands.
You can either

1. try looking at the `*sty` files, in particular `pgfcirctripoles.sty` there most  ports are defined, and cut&paste your way to a new component. If you manage to code it, please send it to me so I can add it for everyone to use :)
2. send me a PNG of how you want the adder to look, and wait for me to code it ^^ I have a few requests in queue, and it is time I updated the package afterall...

Comment: I don’t understand anything in the .sty files :(
Couldn’t you make a Tutorial ?
Thanks for your help, your package is very nice !

Comment: Would it be possible to add Darlington transistor?  I do have some experience with PGF commands, but I was completely lost reading the style file.

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor

Answer (score 6):

Just an update: notice that in version 0.9.0

1. there is a loudspeaker component, and
2. there is an (admittedly short) part about how to add components in the manual.

Unfortunately, to add components you should have a bit of knowledge of the pgf basic layer (part IX of the TikZ-PGF manual).

[image: example circuit for 0.9.9]

Comment: I like necromancer badges! BTW, there is a mux-demux component since 1.0 that can be used to create adders, ALUs, etc...