# How can I add a component to circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Similar to [CircuiTikZ — create new component](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19204/circuitikz-create-new-component)

---

I am using circuitikz to create an electric circuit diagram.
I have found the preset symbol for the zener diode to be different to the symbol I wish to use to represent the zener diode.

---

I have constructed the following code in `tikz` to display the symbol i wish to use.

My question is, How can I store this as a component, to recalled with `[nzD]` like the preset symbols, so that it works in a circuit.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\title{New Zener Diode}

\begin{document}

    \begin{preview}
    \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}

            \draw        (0,0)  --(0.22,0)  to  [open]  (0.78,0)--      (1,0)   ;       % connecting wires          
            \draw [thick](0.22,0)--(0.22,0.35)--(0.78,0)--(0.22,-0.35)--(0.22,0)            % triangle      
                         (0.84,0.35)--(0.78,0.35)--(0.78,-0.35)--(0.72,-0.35)   ;       % vertical

            %\draw       (0,0)              to [zD]                     (1,0)   ;       % preset zener diode

        \end{circuitikz}        
    \end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can’t convert from TikZ code to a PGF shape that is used like you want. But we can surely use the original code from `circuitikz` ’ diode shapes to built our own shape (and to path).

Comment: How can I do that / how can I learn to do that ?
@Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: @Massimo Redaelli

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file `circuitikz1.code.tex` holds all style definition for the Zener diode `zD` and its variant `zD*` and `zDo` as well as the long forms `Zener diode`, `empty Zener diode` and `full Zener diode`.
(The `zD` and `Zener diode` styles switch dynamically to empty or full diodes depending on the styles/options `empty diodes`/`emptydiodes` or `full diodes`/`fulldiodes` respectively.)

These styles are copied to make a `new` Zener diode family.
As we want to use this shape on paths we also need to define a set of `path`s. These are simply copied from the old Zener diode family and are adjusted to match the new shapes.

The actual shape re-definition happens with the `\pgfcircledeclarebipole` macro.
Again, these definitions are copied from the `pgfcircbipoles.sty` file: The names are changed (I added an `n`).

The first path is the path of the triangle, the second path is the path of the line thing in front of it.

```
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-.8\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
```

Notice the additional `.8` in the `\pgfpathmoveto` line?
*That’s it!*

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/diode/height}}{emptynzdiode}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/diode/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/diode/width}}{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfscope
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@circ@res@left}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-.8\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-1.2\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/diode/height}}{fullnzdiode}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/diode/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/diode/width}}{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfscope
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@circ@res@left}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
        \pgfusepath{draw,fill}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-.8\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-1.2\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\tikzset{
    nzD/.style={new Zener diode},
    nzD*/.style={full new Zener diode},
    nzDo/.style={empty new Zener diode},
    new Zener diode/.style={\ifpgf@circuit@fulldiode full \else empty \fi new Zener diode},
    full new Zener diode/.style={\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@fullnzdiode@path},
    empty new Zener diode/.style={\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@emptynzdiode@path},
}
\def\pgf@circ@fullnzdiode@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{fullnzdiode}{#1}}
\def\pgf@circ@emptynzdiode@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{emptynzdiode}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\foreach \diode[count=\x from 0] in {zD,
                    zD*,
                    zDo,
                    nzD,
                    nzD*,
                    nzDo} {
    \draw[yshift=-\x cm] (0,0) to[\diode] (1,0) node[right] {\diode};
}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I can get your code to work fine in the standalone document.

However I am having serious difficulty editing the `circuitikz1.code.tex` file.

Comment: @UnkleRhaukus Do not edit the original file. Instead use your own `.tex` (load with `\input`) or `.sty` file (loading with `\usepackage`, do not include `\makeatletter` and especially not `\makeatother`). What is “serious difficulty”? I suspect that you have also included `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (which is wrong). See for further reference: [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351)

Comment: @UnkleRhaukus There is one major reason why not to edit an existing file: In the case of an update of the `circuitikz` package your own code will be overwritten and be lost. Minor reasons: license, maintainability, …