# Resizing nmos circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'm doing some design for what's inside a D flip flop, with all the transistor, to explain all the basic components that are inside; and I have like 26 mos to fit. I tried to resize them, but the `scale=0.4, transfor shape`command option, kind of mess with my grid (all coordinates are shrinked as well).

So I found this answer [resize nmos symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396003/circuittkz-how-to-mofidy-nmos-symbol), to redraw my nmos smaller, and the problem was the arrow size (too big), then on the circuitikz manual I found the comand `circuitikz/current arrow scale=<your_scaling_factor>` to put in the square brackets after the `nmos` option inside the `node[]{}` command.

But now that I got the right dimensions, the arrow is a bit too low
[image: nmos arrow too low].

Where do I find the right option to lift it up (or down for the pmos)??

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
%       [scale=0.35,trasform shape]
        
        % PUN ffd
        %rectangle to show the pmos
        
        % PDN ffd
        %rectangle to show the nmos

        % Transistor
        \ctikzset{tripoles/mos style=arrows,
                transistors/arrow pos=end,
            }
        % custom nmos dimensions
        \ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/width/.initial=.3} %% .7
        \ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/gate height/.initial=.25}   %% .35
        \ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/base height/.initial=.35}   %% .5
        \ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/conn height/.initial=-0.5}  %% 0
        \ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/height/.initial=.7} %% 1.1
        \ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/base width/.initial=.5} %% .5
        \ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/gate width/.initial=.62}    %% .62

        
        \draw (0,-2) node[nmos,circuitikz/current arrow scale=24,](Mn1){\scriptsize(D)};
        \draw (0,-5) node[nmos,circuitikz/current arrow scale=24,](Mn2){\scriptsize(Y)};

\end{circuitikz}
    \caption{FFD as a one cell with 4 I/O}
    \label{fig:FFD_99}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: If I correctly understend you, than you are looking for something like this: `\draw (0,0) node[nmos, scale=0.4,](Q1){(Y)}` or `\draw (0,0) node[nmos, scale=0.4, font=\Large](Q1){(Y)};`.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but more general. for the scheme I need to draw the transistors must be quite small

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try whenever possible not to mess with the internal parameters... `circuitikz` now has the concept of *class* of a component which can be scaled. The answer you found refers to a (quite) old version of the package. So you can scale all your transistors to be half the default (linear) size:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.72mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style=arrows,
            transistors/arrow pos=end,
            current arrow scale=24,
            transistors/scale=0.5,
        }
\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[nmos,](Mn1){\scriptsize(D)};
        \draw (0,-1) node[nmos,](Mn2){\scriptsize(Y)};
        \path (0,0) ++ (1,0); % bounding box to see the labels
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The arrow is not scaling automatically because it is designed so that it is the same as "current" arrows around the circuit.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed