# CircuiTikZ: Create a command to resize a single component

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, circuitikz, scaling

As frequently asked, I want to resize a single component in a `circuitikz` environment, which is achieved by passing `/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=<length>` to the component options. I have the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw node[ground,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm]{} to [C] (0,2) to [L] (2,2) to [C] (2,0) to node[ground,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm]{} (2,0);
        \draw (2,2) to [pC] (4,2) to [R](4,0) to node[ground,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm]{} (4,0)
        (5,2) node[npn](npn1) {}
        (4,2) to [short] (npn1.base)
        (npn1.emitter) to [R,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm] (5,0)
        to node[ground]{}(5,0)
        (npn1.collector) to[R,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm] (5,4)
        to[short](4,4) to [R] (4,2)
        (5,4) node[vcc] (5,4){$Vcc$}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

I want to scale all the ground nodes but one to have a length of 2cm, and for that I want to create a command, something like `\newcommand{\setsize}[1]{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=#1}` but that does not seem to work. It's just to not having to write all the times `/tikz/circuitikz/...`. That command should work with other components too.

Comment: Have you tried with a style like the one used by @marmot in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495862/38080? Tomorrow I'll try a more general answer...

Comment: If only I knew how to program in LaTeX (I just know the basics)

Comment: How about `\tikzset{my ground/.style={ground,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm}}` and then using `my ground` instead of `ground`. Note that (as far as I understand) `ground` is a shape, and Ti*k*Z is clever enough to find that out, so instead of `node[shape=ground]` it suffices to say `node[ground]`. This also means that in order to change the standard behavior of ground you cannot use `append style` (nor `append code`), but you would have to "hack" it. I would like to argue that it is much better to use your style.

Comment: /tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length is also stored as `\pgf@circ@Rlen`.  This is used to compute all other dimensions.

Comment: Circuitikz stores the dimensions for its components using, for example, `\ctikzset{monopoles/ground/width/.initial=0.25}`.  You can lose the `/.initial` to reset it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer provides you with a way to redefine `ground` but also with a warning. Let's first recall why (or how) `node[ground]` works. `ground` is a shape, not a style. So Ti*k*Z sees that there is no style `ground` defined and then checks the shapes, where it finds it. One could thus intercept at the first stage and just define

```
\tikzset{ground/.style={shape=ground,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm}}
```

Now Ti*k*Z will find a style `ground`, say "Aha, the OP wants me to use the `ground` shape, and to set the bipole length to 2cm. Aye, madam/sir/duck/koala!". This is the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\tikzset{ground/.style={shape=ground,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw node[ground]{} to [C] (0,2) to [L] (2,2) to [C] (2,0) to node[ground]{} (2,0);
        \draw (2,2) to [pC] (4,2) to [R](4,0) to node[ground]{} (4,0)
        (5,2) node[npn](npn1) {}
        (4,2) to [short] (npn1.base)
        (npn1.emitter) to [R,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm] (5,0)
        to node[ground]{}(5,0)
        (npn1.collector) to[R,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm] (5,4)
        to[short](4,4) to [R] (4,2)
        (5,4) node[vcc] (5,4){$Vcc$}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This does work, at least in this example. Note, however, that this is not the most stable approach. What if something intercepts before that? A less vulnerable approach would be to say

```
\tikzset{my ground/.style={shape=ground,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm}}
```

and then to use `my ground` instead of `ground` in the nodes. To motivate this approach a bit more consider the scenario in which someone defines a style `\tikzset{circle/.style={shape=rectangle}}` and causes a lot of confusion. On the other hand, apart from this caveat this method allows you to modify all shapes of `circuitikz` and also `tikz`.

Comment: Marmot, could be an idea, but it's also easy to add it for the shapes you need... There are more than 200 shapes in the package,  and the `to` idiom complicate things.  BTW, I am munging about a change to enable more styling, see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/218 if you want to chime in.

Comment: @Rmano My next task (which I keep postponing and postponing) will be to provide the information which libraries are needed for all the examples in the pgfmanual... Anyway, thanks for doing all this!